# What is a good way to manage large ever growing tables in a database?

Tags: sql, database-design

I am building a web application for medical record keeping. A requirement for this application is logging all changes (view, create, update, delete) to a patients data and pretty much any other useful info in the system (login, cron run, data export, etc).

I am storing the data into a database table currently which is working fine. However it is likely this table will grow unruly very quickly and bloat the database. I am not allowed to delete log entries.

My current plan is to choose an arbitrary size (such as 1 million entries, large but still manageable). When the table hits 1 million entries I move 100,000 oldest entries into a file and store it onto our file server.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue that has other/better ideas on how to handle it?

**Additional info:**
My primary concern is nothing will ever be deleted from this data. However the data does not necessarily need to be accessed after several months. Since this data could logically hit 1 Billion entries in a matter of a couple years (and I have 300 copies of this db that all include this table) what is a good way to manage the size and performance. This table needs to be on a pager which is obviously going to be an issue when it breaks 1 Million let alone 1 Billion.

Comment: You might get familiar with [Table Partitioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx)!

Comment: If 1 million entries is 'large', then you need to take a look at the overall architecture. Many RDBMS platforms perform just fine with tens of millions, or even hundreds of millions of rows. As @PeterSchneider said, look at table partitioning, but such advanced tactics on what is actually a small database is questionable.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA The point isn't the 1 million entries. The point is the table will never have anything deleted and will always be growing. I'm just looking for a scale-able solution to a table that never deletes data. If it would make my point more clear this table could hit 1 billion or more over the span of a couple years.

Comment: What's your actual DBMS? Storing billions of rows is a common task in DBMSes specialized for Data Warehousing. But you will need a bigger system anyway, which is more expensive...

Comment: @dnoeth I'm currently using SQL Server but will probably migrate to MySQL before the table gets too big.

Comment: Having a lot of data in itself is not a problem. There's no such thing as an unruly table, or a bloated database. Are you concerned about running out of disk space, or a degradation in select query performance, or insert performance? Also, if you're going to go open source then consider PostgreSQL as well, as it has table partitioning features and a more advanced query optimiser that may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cases like this are tailor-made for partitioning. Using a partitioning strategy, you span your data across multiple tables. This helps to balance I/O, speed up access times for partition-specific queries, etc. This is a discipline in and of itself, and the choice of partitioning key is crucial. In many cases such as log data like this, people often partition on a datetime value.

[Partitioned Tables and Indexes (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms190787.aspx)

Comment: I think this gives me a healthy perspective of size. I calculated the table will be logging about 4 million entries/year for heaviest usage. So the portioning will probably be enough and archiving can at the least be put off a few years. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thank you for the accepted answer. Best wishes for your solution!